# How can I determine if the arc of the following contour integral vanishes as R approaches infinity?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

The arc is the following integral (this arc is part of a semicircle , where the bottom part is over the real axis, and it traverses in a CCW orientation)

$$ \int_0^\pi {re^{ia}ire^{ia}\over e^{r\cos(a)}e^{ir\sin(a)}}\,da $$

From most examples I have seen the integral vanishes as $ r\rightarrow \infty,$ but how can I prove this? I have looked up Jordan's Lemma and also have seen people use the triangle inequality.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Try showing that this is $$\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{z\,\mathrm{d}z}{e^z}$$

Comment: How can an arc be an integral?

Comment: contour integral , over the complex plane integrals are paths taking from point a to b.